# Creating form inside a div and trying to keep content inside

Tags: html, css, nested

I have been trying for a while to get this formatting to work. I have found so many close examples of what I want, but I just can't seem to get this right.

I am trying to have a form that would "popup" via JS for someone to fill in. I have no issues with the JS and other styling, so I have stripped this down to the most basic example I can that will still illustrate what I am trying to do.

I have a header area that has a "name" and "description" to fill in and most importantly, could have a few other fields dynamically added. The header area might grow by a field or two, so the height is not exactly certain. I want the rest of the form (a scrollable list) to grow or shrink based on the added content of the header.

I have read through so many answers/suggestions and have tried, display:flex; display: table; and Display: grid; and nothing I do seems to work correctly.

I think I am just missing something small (or not), I am at my wits end right now and have spent a few days just trying to get this one form done.

Here is my basic form with out all my attempts, and all I want to do is have the "form-detail" scroll within the remaining space of the "container". I know I can get it to work if I hard-code the heights, however, as I stated above, this can also have extra content added dynamically to the "form-header", so the height of "form-header" is not known.

Essentially, I just need the pink area to stay within the green area (and scroll) with a dynamic blue area height (the two optional fields may hide and show depending...).

Here is the CSS

```
.container {
   position:absolute;
   left:50px;
   top: 50px;
   width: 400px;
   height: 400px;
   background-color: lightgreen;
   text-align: center;
}
.title {
   margin-top:5px;
}
.form-header {
   padding-bottom:10px;
   margin: 5px 5px 5px 5px;
   border-bottom: 2px solid black;
   background-color: lightblue;
}

.form-header input, textarea  { 
   width: 95%;
}

.form-detail {
   margin: 5px 5px 5px 5px;
   background-color: pink;
   overflow-y: scroll;
}
```

Here is the HTML

```
<div class="container">
  <form>
    <div class="form-header">
      <div class="title">Name</div>
      <div><input type="text"></div>
      <div class="title">Description</div>
      <div><textarea type="text" rows="5"></textarea></div>
      <div class="title">Optional 1</div>
      <div><input type="text"></div>
      <div class="title">Optional 2</div>
      <div><input type="text"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="title">List</div>
    <div class="form-detail">
      <div><input type="text"></div>
      <div><input type="text"></div>
      <div><input type="text"></div>
      <div><input type="text"></div>
      <div><input type="text"></div>
      <div><input type="text"></div>
      <div><input type="text"></div>
      <div><input type="text"></div>
      <div><input type="text"></div>
      <div><input type="text"></div>
      <div><input type="text"></div>
      <div><input type="text"></div>
      <div><input type="text"></div>
      <div><input type="text"></div>
      <div><input type="text"></div>
    </div>
  </form>
</div>
```

Fiddle: (https://jsfiddle.net/logan5_42/nz418o9d/14/)

Comment: I am looking to keep the top part (form-header) stationary (not scrolling) and only scroll the list at the bottom.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to use the remained height of the container you can use the following way:

```css
.container {
   position:absolute;
   left:50px;
   top: 50px;
   width: 400px;
   height: 400px;
   background-color: lightgreen;
   text-align: center;
   overflow: hidden;
   display: table;
}
form {
  display: table-row-group;
   height: 100%;
}
.title {
   margin-top:5px;
   display: table-row;
   width: 100%;
}
.form-header {
   padding-bottom:10px;
   margin: 5px 5px 5px 5px;
   border-bottom: 2px solid black;
   background-color: lightblue;
   display: table-row;
    width: 100%;
}

.form-header input, textarea  { 
   width: 95%;
}

.form-detail {
   margin: 5px 5px 5px 5px;
   background-color: pink;
   overflow-y: scroll;
   display: table-row;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
.content-wrapper {
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
  position:relative;
}

.content {
  overflow-y:auto;
  position:absolute;
  left:0;
  top:0;
  right:0;
  bottom:0;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <form>
    <div class="form-header">
      <div class="title">Name</div>
      <div><input type="text"></div>
      <div class="title">Description</div>
      <div><textarea type="text" rows="5"></textarea></div>
      <div class="title">Optional 1</div>
      <div><input type="text"></div>
      <div class="title">Optional 2</div>
      <div><input type="text"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="title">List</div>
    <div class="form-detail">
    <div class="content-wrapper">
      <div class="content">
      <div><input type="text"></div>
      <div><input type="text"></div>
      <div><input type="text"></div>
      <div><input type="text"></div>
      <div><input type="text"></div>
      <div><input type="text"></div>
      <div><input type="text"></div>
      <div><input type="text"></div>
      <div><input type="text"></div>
      <div><input type="text"></div>
      <div><input type="text"></div>
      <div><input type="text"></div>
      <div><input type="text"></div>
      <div><input type="text"></div>
      <div><input type="text"></div>
      </div>
    </div>

    </div>
  </form>
</div>
```

Comment: @Piyper New answer

Comment: Thank you,that was very helpful, I did make a few tweaks, but this was great, seems I just missed adding a few more divs to contain things properly. Thank you again!

Answer (score 0):

Add `overflow-y: auto;` to `.container`

Comment: Thank you for the feed back, however, adding the scroll to the container will make the whole form scroll, I am looking to just have the list at the bottom scroll and keep the top part stationary. Any ideas for that?

Comment: @Piyper Sure, but pichlou beat me to it.  His second answer is exactly what I was going to suggest.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to change your CSS for the container class, keep it like this

```
.container {
   position:absolute;
   left:50px;
   top: 50px;
   width: 400px;
   height: 400px;
   background-color: lightgreen;
   text-align: center;
   overflow-y: scroll;
}
```

I'm adding few more lines just in case you are not liking that default scroll bar, you can easily customize that as well, here you go..

```
::-webkit-scrollbar {
  width: 10px;
}
::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
  background: #f1f1f1; 
}
::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
  background: #888; 
}
::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb:hover {
  background: #555; 
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the feed back, however, adding the scroll to he container will make the whole form scroll, I am looking to just have the list at the bottom scroll and keep the top part stationary. Any ideas for that?

Comment: Change your .form-details css and keep it like this. Give height as much you need, I randomly gave  60px. Hope it's exactly what you are looking for.

.form-detail {
   margin: 5px 5px 5px 5px;
   background-color: pink;   
   overflow-y: scroll !important;
   height: 60px;
}

Comment: Thank you, that would work if the content of the header area stayed the same, however, it can change, the two optional field can be hidden, which changes the height of the header and therefore changes the height of the left over area.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the height:400px from the container class and add min-height as below. Looks like this can help with your problem.

```css
.container {
   position:absolute;
   left:50px;
   top: 50px;
   width: 400px;
   min-height: 200px;
   background-color: lightgreen;
   text-align: center;
}
.title {
   margin-top:5px;
}
.form-header {
   padding-bottom:10px;
   margin: 5px 5px 5px 5px;
   border-bottom: 2px solid black;
   background-color: lightblue;
}

.form-header input, textarea  { 
   width: 95%;
}

.form-detail {
   margin: 5px 5px 5px 5px;
   background-color: pink;
   overflow-y: scroll;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <form>
    <div class="form-header">
      <div class="title">Name</div>
      <div><input type="text"></div>
      <div class="title">Description</div>
      <div><textarea type="text" rows="5"></textarea></div>
      <div class="title">Optional 1</div>
      <div><input type="text"></div>
      <div class="title">Optional 2</div>
      <div><input type="text"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="title">List</div>
    <div class="form-detail">
      <div><input type="text"></div>
      <div><input type="text"></div>
      <div><input type="text"></div>
      <div><input type="text"></div>
      <div><input type="text"></div>
      <div><input type="text"></div>
      <div><input type="text"></div>
      <div><input type="text"></div>
      <div><input type="text"></div>
      <div><input type="text"></div>
      <div><input type="text"></div>
      <div><input type="text"></div>
      <div><input type="text"></div>
      <div><input type="text"></div>
      <div><input type="text"></div>
    </div>
  </form>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you, this change would grow the form to fit the content, however, I would like to keep the size of the form static, keep the header in one spot and scroll the list within the remaining size of the form (400px)

Comment: Yep you can do it; I will edit the answer and fix it with dynamic height.

Answer (score 0):

I changed your demo and fixed it; you must add `overflow: hidden` to the `container` and add a static `height` to `form-detail`.

```css
.container {
   position:absolute;
   left:50px;
   top: 50px;
   width: 400px;
   height: 400px;
   background-color: lightgreen;
   text-align: center;
   overflow: hidden;
}
.title {
   margin-top:5px;
}
.form-header {
   padding-bottom:10px;
   margin: 5px 5px 5px 5px;
   border-bottom: 2px solid black;
   background-color: lightblue;
}

.form-header input, textarea  { 
   width: 95%;
}

.form-detail {
   margin: 5px 5px 5px 5px;
   background-color: pink;
   overflow-y: scroll;
   height: 140px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <form>
    <div class="form-header">
      <div class="title">Name</div>
      <div><input type="text"></div>
      <div class="title">Description</div>
      <div><textarea type="text" rows="5"></textarea></div>
      <div class="title">Optional 1</div>
      <div><input type="text"></div>
      <div class="title">Optional 2</div>
      <div><input type="text"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="title">List</div>
    <div class="form-detail">
      <div><input type="text"></div>
      <div><input type="text"></div>
      <div><input type="text"></div>
      <div><input type="text"></div>
      <div><input type="text"></div>
      <div><input type="text"></div>
      <div><input type="text"></div>
      <div><input type="text"></div>
      <div><input type="text"></div>
      <div><input type="text"></div>
      <div><input type="text"></div>
      <div><input type="text"></div>
      <div><input type="text"></div>
      <div><input type="text"></div>
      <div><input type="text"></div>
    </div>
  </form>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for your feedback, I get that I can hard code the height of the detail, what I was looking for was to have the detail be able to take up the remaining space even if the height of the header changes. is there any way of doing that?